# What does 'cd -' stand for?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In a bash shell script today I noticed the below command at the end of the script. I know what is `cd` but I am unaware of the significance of a dash after it.

```
cd -
```

What does this mean? Google naively truncates the `-` so I am unable to find its answer.

Comment: @n.m. No `man cd` on my machine, FYI.

Comment: Tried that. It will return cd-rom, compact disc, etc.

Comment: You might also want to look at the `pushd` and `popd` commands. I couldn't live without 'em.

Comment: @n.m. - `cd` is not an external binary, it is a command built-in to shells. hint `man bash`.

Comment: I have `man cd` on my system (Gentoo), it says: `This  manual  page is part of the POSIX Programmer's Manual` etc etc. If yours is missing, you can always google `man cd`.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

If a single dash is specified as the argument, it will be replaced by the value of `OLDPWD`.

The `OLDPWD` is set by `cd` command and it is the previous working directory.

Comment: Thanks. This was short and from programmer's point of view, complete.

Comment: what happens if we provide `-` as file.

Comment: @viveksinghggits You can use `cd ./-` or to delete it you can escape it with `rm -fr -- -`

Answer (score 27):

`cd -` returns to the directory you were previously.

For instance:

```
marcelo@marcelo:~$ cd /opt
marcelo@marcelo:/opt$ cd /usr/bin
marcelo@marcelo:/usr/bin$ cd -
/opt
marcelo@marcelo:/opt$
```

I was in /opt, changed to /usr/bin, and then went back to /opt with `cd -`

Answer (score 12):

`cd -` brings you back to the last directory.

```
$ cd ~/Desktop
$ pwd
/Users/daknok/Desktop
$ cd /
$ pwd
/
$ cd -
$ pwd
/Users/daknok/Desktop
```

Answer (score 7):

`cd -` returns to the previous directory you were in.

Say I'm in `/usr/` and I type `cd /var/local/someplace/else`

Then I use `cd -` I'll return to `/usr`

Answer (score 6):

From the manual

> An argument of - is equivalent to $OLDPWD.  If a non-empty directory
>   name from CDPATH is used, or if - is the first argument, and the
>   directory change is successful, the absolute pathname of the new 
>   working  directory is written to the standard output.  The return
>   value is true if the directory was successfully changed; false
>   otherwise

Therefore the `-` is equivalent to the `$OLDPWD`, which holds the last directory which the shell was in, and is set by the previous `cd` invocation.

Answer (score 3):

From the man found here : http://ss64.com/bash/cd.html

```
Quickly get back
$ cd -
```

Answer (score 2):

cd - bring you back to the last directory you were.
e.g.

```
cd ~/Documents
cd ~
cd /
```

Now you are in '/', and if you run 'cd -' you will be in '~'. BTW, run 'cd -' once again, you will return to '/' but not '~/Documents'

Answer (score -2):

“ Current Directory  “ Is what  the bash cd  terminal command means. It means “ keep me in this directory “

Comment: cd means "Changing Directory"!