# subprocess.Popen returns "shell-init: error retrieving current directory"

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, subprocess, reverse-shell

I have created a simple reverse shell in python using `subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)` for the client to run commands. However, when I use commands in the user directory, I get a shell-init error. This is what I get when I try to use `ls`

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
ls: .: Operation not permitted
```

Running the `ls` command as sudo does not work.

It is worth mentioning that commands do work as intended in directories outside of the user directory.

Here is the code that calls the command:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Can you present your python code?

Comment: @YiZhao updated

Comment: The code works for me. What if you call 'ls' in terminal in that directory? It is possible that you have deleted that directory? Add import os print(os.getcwd()) and check if the directory really exists.

Comment: I definitely did not delete the directory. Calling ```ls``` works fine in a regular terminal

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396928/shell-init-error-retrieving-current-directory-getcwd-the-usual-fixes-do-not/41704858 is this related to your problem?

Comment: I know for sure the directory exists. Interestingly, if I cd into the directory and execute ```echo test > test```, the command does execute but my shell stalls and pretends like nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

[From a Chinese blog](https://blog.csdn.net/juyin2015/java/article/details/79233815)

```
[root@smart hello]# cat /root/Desktop/hello.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
[root@smart hello]# /root/Desktop/hello.sh
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
hello
[root@smart hello]# cd /
[root@smart /]# /root/Desktop/hello.sh
hello
[root@smart /]#
```

It says if you remove the first line of the script, it works fine, too.

```
[root@smart hello]# cat /root/Desktop/hello.sh 
echo "hello"
[root@smart hello]# /root/Desktop/hello.sh
hello
```

If this is true for you, too. Then it is not a problem with subprocess.