# Need to understand the difference between two commands in bash programming and what causes them to be

Tags: bash

The commands `cd ../dir2` and `cd ..; cd dir2` are equivalent. However, if one issues
next the command `cd -` the results are different.

Why?

Answer (score 5):

`cd -` will change the current directory to the last one in its history. After executing your first command, `cd ../dir2`, the last directory that `cd -` will read is whatever sibling directory you were in initially. Meanwhile, `cd ..; cd dir2` executes 2 separate commands, therefore writing to history twice, and making the last directory be the parent rather than the sibling.

See this: [What does 'cd -' stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740298/what-does-cd-stand-for)

Answer (score 2):

The `cd` utility only remembers the last directory.  In the second example, it remembers where it was when it did `cd dir2`; in the first, it remembers where it was when it did `cd ../dir2`.  So `cd -` is bound to give different results.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

1. `OLDPWD` is the previous working directory as set by the `cd` command. (see [bash variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables))
2. `cd -` is equivalent to `cd $OLDPWD`. (see [shell builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins))

Comment: Thank you for your quick response