# How to undo "mv file -" command in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mv

As far as you know, `-` has different usages for in combination with different commands in Linux. For example [in combination with  `cd` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740298/what-does-cd-stand-for), it means "*Change directory to the previous location*" and [in combination `mv` or `cat` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/usage-of-dash-in-place-of-a-filename) it means `stdin` or `stdout`.

Unfortunately I wrongly used this character with `mv` command. I wanted to move my file to the previous location which I have been before the change directory but I moved it to `stdin` instead.

Is there any way to recover my file?

I run this command:

```
# mv myfile -
```

Comment: There is no reference to `mv` in the post you linked. `-` is interpreted as `stdin` by `cat` but `mv` doesn't handle `-` in any special way.

Comment: You are right. I was wrong about `-` and `mv`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I moved it to stdin instead.

No, you moved to a file literally named by a dash (you'll use `/dev/stdin` or `/proc/self/fd/0` to refer to the [stdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams), i.e. the [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) 0).

You want to

```
mv -i ./- myfile
```

this is usual practice (to prefix by `./` a strange path). The `-i` interactively asks for confirmation.

Sometimes it is not even easy to type a path for a weird file (e.g. for a file name containing a single newline character). You could use [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) (read about [shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)), e.g. `mv -i ./? file`.

See [mv(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html) and [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) and [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) and [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

The good habit is to avoid strange characters in file paths.

Comment: Does anyone know the man page explaining `/dev/stdin` ? I can't find it!