# cd - vs cd .. explanation

Tags: bash, powershell

Can you explain the difference between these 2 commands:

```
cd ..
```

vs

```
cd -
```

Their results are different when typing them in bash

Comment: I think this question should be in https://superuser.com/

Comment: bash: `cd ..` == go up one directory (to the parent dir); `cd -` == go back to previous directory

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but at least half of the question (`cd -`) is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9740298/3266847). Except that this question here also asks about PowerShell.

Answer (score 3):

The two aren't related.

`..` is an actual directory name; in this case, it's the parent of the current working directory, since it's a relative path. Run `ls -a` in any directory, and you'll see both `.` and `..` in the list of files.

`-`, on the other hand, is an argument handled specially by `cd`, referring to the *previous* working directory. Each time you change directories, the shell performs the equivalent of `OLDPWD=$PWD` just before changing the value of `$PWD`. `-` is just a `cd`-specific synonym for `$OLDPWD`.

Comment: There's a tiny difference between `cd -` and `cd "$OLDPWD"`: `cd -` prints the directory it is changing to, `cd "$OLDPWD"` does not. That (at least to me) makes the latter more useful for scripting.

Comment: Good point, and probably by design. `-` would be more useful as a shortcut in an interactive shell, where the feed back is useful, while `OLDPWD` would be useful in a script, where readability is more important.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is 
`cd` actually switches to the home directory from any directory.

Suppose you are in `/dirname1/dirname2`, `cd`  cmd will switch back to `/`

And `cd ..` will switch to one directory back from the current directory.